# find derivation trees for CFG

Tags: automata, context-free, regular-expressions, discrete-mathematics

I need to draw the derivation tree for $1-2-(3-4)*5*6$ from the grammar below.
 I want to know how many possible derivation trees are there from this grammar.

$$\begin{align}V_n&=\{expr,term,factor,number\}\\
V_t&= \{(,),-,*,0...9\}\\
P&=\left \{
\begin{aligned}
expr&\to expr-expr\;\mid\;term\\
term&\to term*factor\;\mid\;factor\\
factor&\to number \;\mid\; (expr) \\
number&\to 0\mid1\mid2\mid3\mid4\mid5\mid6\mid7\mid8\mid9
\end{aligned}
\right \}\\
S&=expr
\end{align}
$$

The possibilities that I can find are:

$$(1-2)-(((3-4)*5)*6)\\
1-(2-( ((3-4)*5)  *6))$$

Are there other possibilities?

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Comment: @dkaeae hello im trying to edit it

Comment: Also posted on [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3287848/derived-tree-from-cfg). Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without wasting anybody's time. If you don't get a satisfying answer after a week or so, you may flag to request migration.

Comment: @Apass.Jack I disagree. Mathematicians might be interested in this problem as well in my opinion, in particular Theoretical Computer Science topics. You posted an accepted answer (which does not mean that it is the rule), I feel free to post one of the answers to that question, which shows in some cases it can be ok: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234946/292908

Comment: @Ely I have not posted an answer to the current question on either site. So I could not understand when you said, "You posted an accepted answer". You are encouraged to post your answer on either site or both sites. You are especially encouraged to post your answer on this site since questions about parsing of formal languages is more proper to this site.

Comment: @Ely On the other hand, it is generally agreed that cross-site posting should be discouraged. At least all moderators on this site, I believe, agree to that fully. Posting at the same point of time, as in the current case, is heavily frowned upon. It is also clear that the current question is about a routine exercise, which makes it less favorable for cross-site posting. Once again, your intent to answer the question on this site, however, should be appreciated.

Comment: I meant the link you sent in the Meta discussion shows the first (accepted) answer, which suggests that cross-site posting is a No. It is still debatable in my opinion. I wanted to reference the two other answers to that same question on Meta. Please do not discourage people from participating in the first place.

Comment: Anyway, I believe the community dynamics showed that the question is not well received in the other site. At this point one can consider further steps, maybe suggest a deletion or reference this page or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there are no other possibilities as far as I can see.

The ambiguity comes from the production rule $expr \rightarrow expr - expr$. This rule allows you to derive the expression in two different ways:

1. Derive $1$ from the left $expr$ and the rest from the right $expr$
2. Derive $1-2$ from the left $expr$ and the rest from the right $expr$

Some ideas that might help.

The precedences look ok to me; the lower the precedence the closer the operator should be to the root (in this case $expr$).
`-` has the lowest (derived from $expr$), `*` has a higher precedence (derived from a production after $expr$).
And the parentheses `(...)` have the highest (derived from a production after $term$).

The $term$ production rule is left associative, which helps avoid the ambiguity of associativity.

The $expr$ production rule is the problem as mentioned above. A solution to that would be similar to what you see for the $term$ production rule. Make it left associative.

Comment: Thankyou so much!! Clear my confusion!!!! :D